# Dynamic user-created menus with sub-menus in a command line script

Tags: python, console

**Questions:**

- How could this code be written better?
- Could this be written in less lines of code if constructed using classes?
- Also, If the user-created menu items were to be saved to a file for later use, which would be the best approach to use? (pickle? plain text file? etc.)

**Problems:**

- How do I dynamically draw the fixed menu items in the settings menu from a list or dict?
- How to make items selectable by number or a specific character?
- My main struggle came with dynamically displaying and executing sub-menu items.

---

**Preface:**

After about 3 weeks of research, trial and error, playing with different approaches and data structures, I ended up scrapping all my code and resigning myself to writing the following code.

This problem originated as a programming that challenged I created for myself and it now haunts me because I am having to admit defeat by asking you guys for guidance. This drives me crazy since I know there are probably very elegant ways of writing this script, but this was the only way I could make it work and produce the desired outputs.

I have spent hours researching stackoverflow and other sites for similar answers, but none fully addressed my particular design goals, such as dealing with sub-menus and the dynamic nature of this menu system.

I should also mention that I have not fully coded every aspect of this script, but there is enough here to allow the creation of menu items and demonstrate what i'm trying to achieve.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

menu_actions = {}
user_menu_items = []


def add_userItem(item):
  returnitem = "item " + item + " created..."
  return returnitem

def show_settings():
  os.system('clear')

  print "\nEdit"
  print "Default Settings"
  print "\nBack"
  choice = raw_input(" >>  ")
  if choice.lower() == 'back':
    main_menu()
  else:
    decision(choice)
  return

def quit():
  raise SystemExit()

def s_edit():
  os.system('clear')
  print "\nCreate"
  print "Modify"
  print "\nBack\n"
  choice = raw_input(" >>  ")
  if choice.lower() == 'back':
    show_settings()
  else:
    decision(choice)
  return

def s_default():
  os.system('clear')
  choice = raw_input("(**All user created menus will be erased**)\nAre you sure? (YES / NO)  or Back\n >>  ")
  if choice.lower() == 'back':
    show_settings()
  elif choice.lower() == 'yes':
    print 'all settings have been set to default'
    del user_menu_items[:]  # removing all items from user menu
    show_settings()
  elif choice.lower() == 'no':
    show_settings()
  return

def e_create():
  go = True
  addeditem = []
  global user_menu_items
  while go:      
    badinput = False
    if badinput == True:
      print "That's not a selection. Please try again..."
    else:
      os.system('clear')
      if addeditem != '':
        z = 0
        for i in addeditem:
          print(addeditem[z])
          z += 1
      if not user_menu_items:
        print
      print "\n**Menu Items**"
      z = 0
      for i in user_menu_items:
        print(user_menu_items[z])
        z += 1
      choice = raw_input("\nCreate New Item? (YES / NO)\n >>  ")
    if choice.lower() == 'yes':
      additem = raw_input("\n\nSpecify Name of New Menu Item: ")
      addeditem.append(add_userItem(additem))
      user_menu_items.append(additem)
    else:
      if choice.lower() == 'no':
    go = False
      else: 
    badinput = True
  s_edit()
  return

def e_modify():
  os.system('clear')
  print "Rename"
  print "Delete"
  print "Move Item"
  print "\nBack\n"
  choice = raw_input("Choose an action: ")
  return choice

def m_rename():
  os.system('clear')
  print "\nBack\n"
  choice = raw_input("Enter a new name: ")
  return choice

def m_delete():
  os.system('clear')
  print "\nBack\n"
  choice = raw_input("Select Menu Item to Delete: ")
  return choice

def m_move():
  os.system('clear')
  print "\nBack\n"
  choice = raw_input("Specify new location: ")
  return choice

def goback():
  os.system('clear')
  print "\nBack\n"
  decision('')
  return

def user_menu():
  z = 0
  for i in user_menu_items:
    print(user_menu_items[z])
    z += 1
  return

def main_menu():
  os.system('clear')
  user_menu()
  print "\nSettings"
  print "Quit"
  choice = raw_input(" >>  ")
  decision(choice)
  return

def decision(decision):
  dec = decision.lower()
  if dec == '':
    menu_actions['main menu']()
  else:  
    try:
      menu_actions[dec]()
    except KeyError:
      print "invalid selection, please try again.\n"
      menu_actions['main menu']()
  return

menu_actions = {
  'main': main_menu,
  'settings': show_settings,
  'quit': quit,
  'edit': s_edit,
  'default': s_default,
  'create': e_create,
  'modify': e_modify,
  'rename': m_rename,
  'delete': m_delete,
  'move': m_move,
  'back' : goback
  }

main_menu()
```

**About:**
As you can see, I have designed a menu creator based on user input, while still providing a fixed menu system for creating and modifying the user-created menus. My desire was to display one tier at a time, making menu items numerically selectable (except for "go back" and "quit"). Below is a pseudo code view of my desired menu tree.

I should also mention that I am fully aware of the fact that the user-created menu items will not have any particular functionality, but I figured I could use this program to create the menus and then code functionality later on -- if desired.

**Desired Menu Tree:**

> 1. Settings
>
>    1. Edit Menu
>
>       1. Create   > # Specify Location of Menu Item. > # Specify Name of New Menu Item.
>       2. Modify   > # Select Menu Item to Modify. > # Pick an Action?
>
>          1. Rename > # Enter a new name
>          2. Delete > # Select Menu Item to Delete.
>          3. Move Item  > # Where?
>
>       x. Go Back
>    2. Default Settings (**All user created menus will be erased**) > #Are you sure? (YES / NO?)
>
> x. Quit > #exit program

Comment: Can you fix the indentation so that your initial code and intent can be undetstood ? Your code doesn't runs with current indentation. Start fixing with line#63

Comment: All fixed, sorry about that, when I copied the text over and then specified it as code, stackexchange didn't recognize all of my indentions. You should be good to go now.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : your code is not indented properly and I cannot run it. Also, it seems a bit convoluted to me so I haven't really tried to understand it. However, here are a few comments that might help you if you want to improve your code.

---

**Keep it simple**

```
def add_userItem(item):
  returnitem = "item " + item + " created..."
  return returnitem
```

could be

```
def add_userItem(item):
  return "item " + item + " created..."
```

---

`goback` could just call `main_menu()` instead of `decision('')`. This would make `decision()` much simpler as it shouldn't be its duty to try to handle special cases (see [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns))

---

You don't need to have `menu_actions` at the top of your file.

---

`return` at the end of the function is not required if you don't plan to return any value.

---

```
  choice = raw_input("Choose an action: ")
  return choice
```

could be

```
  return raw_input("Choose an action: ")
```

---

---

**For Loop**

The way Python loops is designed is supposed to help you to write concise and expressive code : what you write should match pretty closely how you think about things : "I want to do this for each item in this container" instead of "I want to have this index and I start at 0 and I increment and I get the element at this index...".

```
    z = 0
    for i in addeditem:
      print(addeditem[z])
      z += 1
```

should be written :

```
    for i in addeditem:
      print(i)
```

How nice is this ?

Pretty much everytime you initialise a variable at 0 to use it as an index in a loop you are doing it wrong. If you really need to know what is the current index, enumerate is what you are looking for.

---

---

**Don't repeat yourself**

```
  for i in user_menu_items:
    print(i)
```

appears in your code twice. You should just call `user_menu`.

---

Multiple methods looks quite similar, it might be worth defining a more generic function and then just calling it everywhere

---

```
  if choice.lower() == 'back':
    show_settings()
  elif choice.lower() == 'yes':
    print 'all settings have been set to default'
    del user_menu_items[:]  # removing all items from user menu
    show_settings()
  elif choice.lower() == 'no':
    show_settings()
```

calls `lower()` and `show_settings` in 3 different places.
It might be easier to do something like :

```
  choice = raw_input("(**All user created menus will be erased**)\nAre you sure? (YES / NO)  or Back\n >>  ").lower()
  if choice == 'yes':
    print 'all settings have been set to default'
    del user_menu_items[:]  # removing all items from user menu
    show_settings()
  elif choice in ['back','no']:
    show_settings()
```

---

If you ever change the label of `menu` (which most likely happened already - I assume that `main menu` is its old name), things will fail and you'll have to fix it in different places in `decision`.

What about doing :

```
def decision(decision):
    try:
      menu_actions[decision.lower()]()
    except KeyError:
      print "invalid selection, please try again.\n"
      main_menu()
```

---

**Documentation**

You should add comments at least to describe the program and the different main functions.

Comment: This is excellent feedback, thank you Josay. I am new to programming and only recently began being more disciplined with using comments. I will go back and work on it cleaning things up a bit before submitting my edits. Thanks!